# Web bluetooth api throws an error "unsupported device" when connect method is called

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am able to see the devices and when I try calling the `connect()` method on the device it throws an error:

> Unsupported Device.

The device I am trying to connect to is an Android phone, what could be possible reason I am unable to connect or how can I get past this error and connect successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Web Bluetooth API only works with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) /4.0 devices. I got the same error when I tried to connect with a Sphero 2.0 which doesn't have BLE but Bluetooth 2.0 instead.
But it seems to work with the Sphero BB-8 and Ollie which are BLE devices, so I would assume your android phone is not a BLE device neither.